# Recode dates to study day within subject

Tags: r, recode

I have data in which subjects completed multiple ratings per day over 6-7 days. The number of ratings per day varies. The data set includes subject ID, date, and the ratings. I would like to create a new variable that recodes the dates for each subject into "study day" --- so 1 for first day of ratings, 2 for second day of ratings, etc.

For example, I would like to take this:

```
id  Date    Rating
1   10/20/2018  2
1   10/20/2018  3
1   10/20/2018  5
1   10/21/2018  1
1   10/21/2018  7
1   10/21/2018  9
1   10/22/2018  4
1   10/22/2018  5
1   10/22/2018  9
2   11/15/2018  1
2   11/15/2018  3
2   11/15/2018  4
2   11/16/2018  3
2   11/16/2018  1
2   11/17/2018  0
2   11/17/2018  2
2   11/17/2018  9
```

And end up with this:

```
id  Day Date    Rating
1   1   10/20/2018  2
1   1   10/20/2018  3
1   1   10/20/2018  5
1   2   10/21/2018  1
1   2   10/21/2018  7
1   2   10/21/2018  9
1   3   10/22/2018  4
1   3   10/22/2018  5
1   3   10/22/2018  9
2   1   11/15/2018  1
2   1   11/15/2018  3
2   1   11/15/2018  4
2   2   11/16/2018  3
2   2   11/16/2018  1
2   3   11/17/2018  0
2   3   11/17/2018  2
2   3   11/17/2018  9
```

I was going to look into setting up some kind of loop, but I thought it would be worth asking if there is a more efficient way to pull this off. Are there any functions that would allow me to automate this sort of thing? Thanks very much for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to reset the count after every `id` , makes this question a bit different.

Using only base R, we can `split` the `Date` based on `id` and then create a count of each distinct group.

```
df$Day <- unlist(sapply(split(df$Date, df$id), function(x) match(x,unique(x))))


df
#   id       Date Rating Day
#1   1 10/20/2018      2   1
#2   1 10/20/2018      3   1
#3   1 10/20/2018      5   1
#4   1 10/21/2018      1   2
#5   1 10/21/2018      7   2
#6   1 10/21/2018      9   2
#7   1 10/22/2018      4   3
#8   1 10/22/2018      5   3
#9   1 10/22/2018      9   3
#10  2 11/15/2018      1   1
#11  2 11/15/2018      3   1
#12  2 11/15/2018      4   1
#13  2 11/16/2018      3   2
#14  2 11/16/2018      1   2
#15  2 11/17/2018      0   3
#16  2 11/17/2018      2   3
#17  2 11/17/2018      9   3
```

---

I don't know how I missed this but thanks to @thelatemail who reminded that this is basically the same as

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(Day = match(Date, unique(Date)))
```

AND

```
df$Day <- as.numeric(with(df, ave(Date, id, FUN = function(x) match(x, unique(x)))))
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: `split(df$Date, df$id, df$Date)` seems odd to me - I don't think you can just keep passing more arguments to `...` to split by. `split(df$Date, list(df$id, df$Date))` gives different results for instance.

Comment: @thelatemail ohh..wait! You are right. I just need to `split` it by `id` no need of `Date`. It ignores `df$Date` here anyway I think. I'll update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just struck me too - `sapply + split` is `tapply`, so `unlist(tapply(df$Date, df$id, FUN=function(x) match(x,unique(x))))` would do it too if the id's are always in order. Also, `ave` could do it by the same logic - `ave(as.numeric(df$Date), df$id, FUN=function(x) match(x,unique(x)))`

Comment: yes, if ids are in order then those solution would work and it also means that this should be a dupe then? There should be answers giving that kind of output.

Comment: Many thanks for the additional comments and options, everyone. It is very helpful to see various alternatives as I try to learn r.  And my apologies if I missed another posting addressing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a slightly hacky `dplyr` version....you can use the date column and convert it to a numeric date then manipulate that number to give the desired result

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- data_frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                     Date= c('10/20/2018', '10/20/2018', '10/20/2018', '10/21/2018', '10/21/2018', '10/21/2018',
                             '10/22/2018', '10/22/2018', '10/22/2018','11/15/2018', '11/15/2018', '11/15/2018',
                             '11/16/2018', '11/16/2018', '11/17/2018', '11/17/2018', '11/17/2018'), 
                     Rating=c(2,3,5,1,7,9,4,5,9,1,3,4,3,1,0,2,9))

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(
    Date = mdy(Date),
    Day = as.numeric(Date),
    Day = Day-min(Day)+1)

# A tibble: 17 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
      id Date       Rating   Day
   <dbl> <date>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 2018-10-20      2     1
 2     1 2018-10-20      3     1
 3     1 2018-10-20      5     1
 4     1 2018-10-21      1     2
 5     1 2018-10-21      7     2
 6     1 2018-10-21      9     2
 7     1 2018-10-22      4     3
 8     1 2018-10-22      5     3
 9     1 2018-10-22      9     3
10     2 2018-11-15      1     1
11     2 2018-11-15      3     1
12     2 2018-11-15      4     1
13     2 2018-11-16      3     2
14     2 2018-11-16      1     2
15     2 2018-11-17      0     3
16     2 2018-11-17      2     3
17     2 2018-11-17      9     3
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach!