# How can I create a day number variable in R based on dates?

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchical-data, mixed-models, recode

I want to create a variable with the number of the day a participant took a survey (first day, second day, thirds day, etc.)
The issue is that there are participants that took the survey after midnight.
For example, this is what it looks like:

| Id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 08/03/2020 08:17 |
| 1 | 08/03/2020 12:01 |
| 1 | 08/04/2020 15:08 |
| 1 | 08/04/2020 22:16 |
| 2 | 07/03/2020 08:10 |
| 2 | 07/03/2020 12:03 |
| 2 | 07/04/2020 15:07 |
| 2 | 07/05/2020 00:16 |
| 3 | 08/22/2020 09:17 |
| 3 | 08/23/2020 11:04 |
| 3 | 08/24/2020 00:01 |
| 4 | 10/03/2020 08:37 |
| 4 | 10/03/2020 11:13 |
| 4 | 10/04/2020 15:20 |
| 4 | 10/04/2020 23:05 |

This is what I want:

| Id | date | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08/03/2020 08:17 | 1 |
| 1 | 08/03/2020 12:01 | 1 |
| 1 | 08/04/2020 15:08 | 2 |
| 1 | 08/04/2020 22:16 | 2 |
| 2 | 07/03/2020 08:10 | 1 |
| 2 | 07/03/2020 12:03 | 1 |
| 2 | 07/04/2020 15:07 | 2 |
| 2 | 07/05/2020 00:16 | 2 |
| 3 | 08/22/2020 09:17 | 1 |
| 3 | 08/23/2020 11:04 | 2 |
| 3 | 08/24/2020 00:01 | 2 |
| 4 | 10/03/2020 08:37 | 1 |
| 4 | 10/03/2020 11:13 | 1 |
| 4 | 10/04/2020 15:20 | 2 |
| 4 | 10/04/2020 23:05 | 2 |

How can I create the day variable taking into consideration participants that who took the survey after midnight still belong to the previous day?

I tried the codes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808031/recode-dates-to-study-day-within-subject). But I have issues with participants taking surveys after midnight.

Comment: You say that after midnight is a problem, so you need to define a cutoff beyond which it will actually be the next day. For instance, `00:16` should be "yesterday", what about `00:30`? `00:50`? At what point does "next day" _really mean_ the next day?

Comment: FYI, to do this right, you should likely convert your `date` field to a POSIXt` class so that you can do comparisons like this more easily. I suggest `quux$date <- as.POSIXct(quux$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")` (where `quux` is whatever your frame is named).

Comment: @r2evans thank you,  the cutoff point is at 02:00. Then which code should I use to define the cutoff and create the day variable when having multiple measurements per participant?

Comment: @MAIMAU In the example, for ID 3, should `07/22/2020 09:17` be `08/22/2020 09:17`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

### code

```r
data2 <- data %>% 
  mutate(date2 = as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number(), 
         date3 = as.Date(ifelse(row == 1, date2, NA), origin = "1970-01-01")) %>% 
  fill(date3) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(diff = as.numeric(date2 - date3 + 1)) %>% 
  select(-date2, -date3, -row)
```

### output

```r
#>   id             date diff
#> 1  1 08/03/2020 08:17    1
#> 2  1 08/03/2020 12:01    1
#> 3  1 08/04/2020 15:08    2
#> 4  1 08/04/2020 22:16    2
#> 5  2 07/03/2020 08:10    1
#> 6  2 07/03/2020 12:03    1
#> 7  2 07/04/2020 15:07    2
#> 8  2 07/05/2020 00:16    3
```

Comment: It seems that it works and it counted midnight as taken in the previous day, but when checking duplicates (I have a third variable called beep which indicates the measurement number of the day) it says I have duplicates: check.nodup(interaction(diff, beep), id, data=dat). I can't find where is the problem and both beep and day (diff) variables seem to be ok. I think there might be one row with an error. My data includes more than 3000 observations, so it is difficult to check

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that explicitly will show dates considered. First, would make sure your `date` is in POSIXct format as suggested in comments (if not done already). Then, if the `hour` is less than 2 (midnight to 2 AM) subtract 1 from the date so the `survey_date` reflects the day before. If the `hour` is not less than 2, just keep the date. The timezone `tz` argument is set to "" to avoid confusion or uncertainty. Finally, after grouping by `Id`, subtract each `survey_date` from the `first` `survey_date` to get number of days since first survey. You can use `as.numeric` to make this column numeric if desired.

Note: if you want to just note consecutive days taken the survey (and ignore gaps in days between surveys) you can substitute for the last line:

```
mutate(day = cumsum(survey_date != lag(survey_date, default = first(survey_date))) + 1)
```

This will increase `day` by 1 every new `survey_date` found for a given `Id`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz = "")) %>%
  mutate(survey_date = if_else(hour(date) < 2, 
                              as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "") - 1, 
                              as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = ""))) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(day = survey_date - first(survey_date) + 1)
```

**Output**

```
      Id date                survey_date day   
   <int> <dttm>              <date>      <drtn>
 1     1 2020-08-03 08:17:00 2020-08-03  1 days
 2     1 2020-08-03 12:01:00 2020-08-03  1 days
 3     1 2020-08-04 15:08:00 2020-08-04  2 days
 4     1 2020-08-04 22:16:00 2020-08-04  2 days
 5     2 2020-07-03 08:10:00 2020-07-03  1 days
 6     2 2020-07-03 12:03:00 2020-07-03  1 days
 7     2 2020-07-04 15:07:00 2020-07-04  2 days
 8     2 2020-07-05 00:16:00 2020-07-04  2 days
 9     3 2020-08-22 09:17:00 2020-08-22  1 days
10     3 2020-08-23 11:04:00 2020-08-23  2 days
11     3 2020-08-24 00:01:00 2020-08-23  2 days
12     4 2020-10-03 08:37:00 2020-10-03  1 days
13     4 2020-10-03 11:13:00 2020-10-03  1 days
14     4 2020-10-04 15:20:00 2020-10-04  2 days
15     4 2020-10-04 23:05:00 2020-10-04  2 days
```